# PC through Yamaha receiver: No 5.1 audio?

Tags: windows-7, audio, 5.1, home-theater

I have a Windows 7 machine hooked up to a Yamaha receiver via HTML, which is hooked up to a Samsung LED, also via HDMI. It all seems to work fine, except 5.1 doesn't seem to work. I get 2 channel audio. I've run the 5.1 tests from within the audio playback device list and also run the Fraunhofer HTML5 AAC Audio Playback Tests - Multichannel and both worked fine. However, when I playback a movie through my Chrome browser (Netflix, AmazonPrime, Kodi sources) it always plays back without surround.

One thing I noticed is that when the TV is on, Win7's display settings sees the Samsung. When the TV is off, it sees the Yamaha receiver. In other words, it seems to ignore that there's a receiver there if the TV is on. Is that a problem, or business as usual?

Any info you can share is greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTML isn't an audio-transfer protocol or cable type. Can you please check the connection type and edit your question to clarify?

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is that the audio being sent is to the screen, and the screen is only stereo. You may need to adjust your audio device properties or connect to the the amplifier with its own cable to the computer and not through the screen.

Comment: Let's assume you meant HDMI rather than HTML. HDMI will, by default, send sound to the same place it sends picture. Try using something like http://audioswit.ch/er [yes, that's the real URL] to change output devices.